# Does strcpy_s can return when parameters are invalid?

Tags: c++, c, crt

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-160) for `strcpy_s()` clearly explains when [parameter validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/parameter-validation?view=msvc-160) will fail.

Is using the [`_set_invalid_parameter_handler()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-invalid-parameter-handler-set-thread-local-invalid-parameter-handler?view=msvc-160) the only way to return from a call to `strcpy_s()` and handle errors ?

Comment: The sort of errors caught by parameter validation are all preventable. It's not like `fopen` failing on a missing file. That's why you don't need ordinary error handling.

Comment: @MSalters, my point is that if parameter validation fails, the call to strcpy_s qill never return. It exits my whole application (Like an exit(-1));